# insert_rows in Openpyxl is not updating the row count in existing formulas and not picking the above row format

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When I manually insert a row in between 2 and 5 rows(=sum(F2:F5)), the formula is updated with new count(=sum(F2:F6)) in excel, but with Openpyxl the same is not happening after adding new row the formula remains same(=sum(F2:F5)).

Please let us know if there is any approach to edit the existing excel file(.xlsx) without disturbing the existing format and formulas

Comment: You'll have to edit the formulae yourself though you can use the formula tokeniser to do this.

Comment: @CharlieClark need the above row format

Comment: What's the problem? Look at the source for `Worksheet.move_range()` to see how to do this.

Comment: @CharlieClark tried Worksheet.move_range(), format and formulas are not updated

Comment: `ws.move_range(rows=4, cols=2, translate=True)`

Comment: According to the [current docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html) for `.move_range()`: "Formulae and references will not be updated"

Answer (score 0):

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae

> openpyxl never evaluates formula but it is possible to check the name of a formula:

openpyxl has [very limited support for manipulating formula](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html) but I really don't think it implicitly parses and manipulates them when you open & manipulate documents.

Comment: `move_range(translate=True)` supports it but only this.